# swift3 for loop with two counter

Tags: for-loop, swift3

My question seams to be quite easy but currently I am not seeing the wood for the trees.

I've written code in `swift 2` using a `for-loop` with two counter like:

```
for var i = 0, j = 1; i < 5; i++, j++ {
 code...
}
```

but, with `swift 3` this become deprecated.

I mean with one variable it's clear:

```
for i in 0 ..< endcondition {
  code...
}
```

but how would the code with a `for-loop` looks like in `swift 3` with two counter, without interlacing two `for-loop`?

Thanks in advance
Stefan

Answer (score 2):

In this particular case

```
for i in 0..<5 {
  let j = i + 1
  print(i, j)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, looks elegant, but this works just dependently to "i". What I was looking for was a statement where I can set and increment "j" independently for "i" and to any value together with the initial "i" statement.

Comment: That's why I wrote *in this particular case*. My code does the same as your example. But you could create a variable before the loop and increment it in the loop with `var += 1`

Answer (score 0):

```
var i:Int = 0
var j:Int = 1
for each in 0...arrayCount -1{
    //do stuff
    /// place increments in closures as needed
    j += 1
    i += 1
}

You may want to consider on while loop to allow usage of evaluating multiple values to signal a stop.

while condition {
      statements
      Change condition
 }
```